# Python, mathematic operations on variables

Tags: python, math, python-3.7

In python 3 I was wondering if there was a way to get a variable from an input like this:

```
x = input("-> ")
```

And if x was this:

```
x = "1 + 10"
```

Is there a way to perform this operation and return it as a different variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate the mathematical expression inside the variable like so.

```
In [1]: x = "1 + 10"                                                                                                                                                                

In [2]: eval(x)                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[2]: 11
```